# Ruby, string with a mathematical calculation

Tags: ruby

In this challenge you must implement the method code that receives a string with a mathematical calculation and returns the value that ? must have for the account result to be correct.

'100 + ? + 3 = 108'

How to find ? value in ruby.

can someone explain how to solve?

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ to solve this yourself?  The question is very broad and likely to attract opinion-based answer as to the best way to solve it

Comment: No, I have no idea to start. It's a challenge for beginners, but I think it's very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are really dumb and need to be told what to do.

Try solving the problem yourself by hand and when it's very clear for you how to solve it, try to implement it.

I'll give you a start

- Validate if the input is empty or nil
- Split the input into its parts `'100 + ? + 3 = 108'` => `["100", "+", "?", "+", "3", "=", "108"]` (you can put them in an array)
- Check if each part is a number, an operator or a `?`
- If it's a number, transform it from string to number
- if It's an operator check which one, +, -, etc. and then act on it taking left and right side of the operator

etc. etc

You'll notice it's not trivial, but eventually each one of those paragraphs can be translated into specific ruby code.

Give it a try and ask again when you get stuck.

Comment: I agree approach this like it was as if it was a parser for a computer language.